# Is there a way to show the type of every column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I use `dtype` to show the types of the columns, but most of the types will appear as `object` and you need to check it individually by using the `type()` method to know, for example, if it is an `str` actully.

Is there a better way to get it str or `numpy.int64` from the first place and not having to check them individually?

```
df_08.dtypes

>>>model                    object
displ                   float64
cyl                      object
trans                    object
drive                    object
fuel                     object
veh_class                object
air_pollution_score      object
city_mpg                 object
hwy_mpg                  object
cmb_mpg                  object
greenhouse_gas_score     object
smartway                 object
dtype: object
```

```
type(df_18['air_pollution_score'][1])
>>> numpy.int64
```

and there is no nan values in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have empty values in these "object" columns. Pandas stores empty values as 'nan' which is a float. If that's intermixed with other types like ints or strings, then the whole column is marked as having a dtype of "object" (it's unknown because no other single dtype applies to the whole column).

To check this, look at the output of:

```
{type(val) for val in df_18['air_pollution_score']}
```

You could get the dtype of all non-null objects using the following trick:

```
{col: df_18.loc[~pd.isnull(df_18[col]), col].dtype for col in df_18}
```

If that still doesn't work, you can just check all the types individually:

```
{col: set(df.loc[~pd.isnull(df[col]), col].apply(type).drop_duplicates()) for col in df}
```

Comment: I checked the dataframe earlier and there is no empty data model  using df_18.isna().sum()

Comment: @naa0aan Please add that information to your question, most pandas users are going to expect that to be the culprit for this behavior as it's very common

Comment: @naa0aan edited my answer to show how to get a set of types

Answer (score 0):

Just do with `applymap` with `type` , and when the columns type is object , it will have change , it is mixed datatype, if you only check the position 1 in the columns , you may get wrong output for the whole columns

```
df.applymap(type)
```

Answer (score 0):

dtypes is the right answer but it seems that you have mixed dtypes in your columns. As soon as pandas sees a columns with multiple types in it, it automatically casts it into object dtype.

Can you post the result of `df_18.air_pollution_score.apply(type).unique()` ?

Comment: `array([<class 'int'>], dtype=object`